# How do I add og:image script in meta?

Tags: meta-tags

My facebook is grabbing the wrong image.

I try to adding this open graph image in my head.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $_GET['image'] ?>" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>
```

but the content image path is not shown. 
It became this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

I want it to be like this.
If the article A have image a_name.jpg, the meta will be `<meta property="og:image" content="/images/a_name.jpg"/>`

If the article B have image b_name.jpg, the meta will be `<meta property="og:image" content="/images/b_name.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the tag the full URL to the image. If you install the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module not only can you have full control over keyword, description, etc. but also all the og tags too per node.

Comment: I want the Metatag open graph image has a unique image path in every pages.

Insert a URL will define showing the same image all articles.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm saying, and the Metatag module does it for you

Comment: What is the code should I put?

Comment: No code, install the module and when editing the node in the vertical tabs at the bottom one is called Meta tags and you can override the default settings

Comment: I get you. It needs to add in every node.